# Beginning Development in Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, beta

I'm thinking of starting a web project to which I eventually will publish online. I want to take advantage of the latest technologies and am wondering if it's possible for me to begin development using VS 11 Beta for this project. If I do, can I upgrade to the RTM release without issues? I feel it will help me learn the new features of .Net 4.5 as well as MVC 4. I don't want to begin using this beta version though to realize that once the RTM release comes out none of it will work or run into issues...

Comment: I would say go for it. There is *some small risk* of breaking changes, but given the team's effort to keep 11 compatible with 2010, you should be fine.

Comment: It's a *beta*. The term itself says it: *use me, but don't make any assumptions about stability whatsoever*.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 RC will be out soon. I can tell you bundling has changed significantly from Beta to RC. There will be many changes between Beta and RTM. We hope to minimize the changes from RC to RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can tell you whether what you do now will work 100% without issues when RTM comes out. But I doubt there are doing to be major breaking changes with MVC4 between now and release.

Comment: Pretty logical, thanks. I guess I'll go for it then.

Comment: I would go for it. I will be starting to use VS11 in the next couple of weeks when current block of work is done.

Comment: I can say you better plan on changes from Beta to RTM. That wouldn't stop me from using the beta, just plan for some work for the next release.

Comment: Nah I figured that much, was just hoping for a suggestion if others believed I should be generally "OK", based on other's past experiences as well as if anyone else might be doing the same thing.